# Calculating the yaw given a difference in longitude and latitude

Tags: trigonometry

Image describing the problem:

[image: Imgur]

I am trying to find the angle φ, which is the yaw(view angle) between point B to C, from the axis y. The knowns are as follows:

- Distances BD, AB and BC
- Angles θ, α and β.

Is there a function which gives us the yaw and whose output is defined from 0 to 2π?